# Не пойму как в django сохранить форму FK?

Tags: python, django, request

1. 1.Где почитать про такое объявления `request.POST`, `request.FILES`? В инете не нашел.
2. **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' - как исправить? Я так понимаю, нужно kwargs ему, тоже не нашел в инете
3. сохранить Court > ForengKye > CourtInfo после того как сделал commint=False должен взять id.Form = CourtInfo.save()?

Model.py

```
class InfoCourt(models.Model):
    """Информация о деле"""

    status = models.ForeignKey(
        Status,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Статус  дела',
        related_name='court_status',
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True
                               )
    judge = models.ForeignKey(
        judge,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Судья',
        related_name='court_judge',
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True
                               )

    case_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=24,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Номер Судебного дела')
    uid_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=26,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='УИД Судебного дела')
    data_reg = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Дата регистрации дела')
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        ListCourt,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        related_name='location', verbose_name='Место  ')
    message = models.TextField(
        max_length=50000,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Результат события Коментарий')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.uid_number

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Информация дела"
        verbose_name_plural = "Информация дела"
        ordering = ['-created']

    def get_list(self):
        return self.location.name

class Court(models.Model):
    """Таблица оперций связанных с  судебным процессом """

    info_court = models.ForeignKey(
        InfoCourt,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='info_courts',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Список юр.оперций '
            )

    procedure = models.ForeignKey(
        Procedure,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='procedure',
        verbose_name='Наименование события')
    worker = models.ForeignKey(
        worker,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='worker',
        verbose_name='Отв-ный')
    data_finish = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Срок исполнения С')
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Начало исполнения С')
    date_stop = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Завершения исполнения С')
    akt_end = models.ForeignKey(
        ListEnd,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=None,
        related_name='akt_end',
        verbose_name='Событие утверждения')
    time_stop = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Время завершение операции ')
    file_paste = models.FileField(
        upload_to='upload/Courtdoc/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='"Файл прикрепленный')
    curt_hall = models.CharField(
        max_length=24,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Номер кабинета заседания')
    message = models.CharField(
        max_length=50000,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Результат,коментарий события ')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.procedure

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Оперция судопроизводства"
        verbose_name_plural = "Оперции судопроизводства"
        ordering = ['created']
```

forms.py

```
class CourtInfoForm(ModelForm):
    """Форма справочной информации о судебном деле"""

    class Meta:
        model = InfoCourt
        fields = [
            "case_number",
            "uid_number",
            "data_reg",
            "location",
            "status",
            "message",
            ("judge"),


        ]

        widgets = {

            "case_number": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'type': 'text',
                'placeholder': 'Номер  дела'

            }),
            "uid_number": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'УИД дела'
            }),
            "data_reg": DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Дата  регистрации в суде',
                'data-date-container': '#datepicker2',
                'data-provide': 'datepicker',
                'data-date-autoclose': 'true',
                'data-date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',

            }),
            "location": Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Судебная инстанция'

            }),
            "judge": Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Судья '

            }),
            "status": Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Статус дела'

            }),
            "message": Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'type': 'text',
                'placeholder': 'Комментарий к делу  '

            }),
        }
class CourtForm(ModelForm):
    """Форма оперций связанных с  судебным процессом """

    class Meta:
        model = Court
        exclude =["message"]
        widgets = {

            "message": Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'name': "area",

                'placeholder': 'Результат,коментарий события '

            }),
            "file_paste": FileInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Прикрепить документ',

                }),

            "date_start": DateInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Начало исполнения ',

                'data-date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            }),

            "data_finish": DateInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Срок исполнения ',

                'data-date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            }),
            "procedure": Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Процедура '

            }),
            "akt_end": Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Утверждение '

            }),
            "worker": Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Отв-ный'

            })
        }
```

views.py

```
def court_event_add(request, pk):
    """Создание-добавление  нового судебного события"""

    accident = Accident.objects.get(id=pk)
    accident_pk = accident.pk
    court_info = accident.court_info
    if request.method == 'POST':
        CourtForms = CourtForm(**request.POST, **request.FILES, prefix='court_forms', instance=Court)
        if CourtForms.is_valid():
            form = CourtForms.save(commit=False)
            # Не ясно тут 
            CourtForms.info_court = form
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    CourtForms = CourtForm(prefix='court_forms',)
    template_name = 'dist/court/event/read_court_add_event.html'
    data = {'court_info': court_info,
            'court': CourtForms,
            'court_list': court_list,
            'accident_pk': accident_pk
            }

    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

Comment: Предоставьте html файл, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

def court_event_add(request, pk):
"""Создание-добавление  нового судебного события"""

```
accident = Accident.objects.get(id=pk)
accident_pk = accident.pk
court_info = accident.court_info.info_courts.all()
for item in court_info:
    item.pk, item.info_court
    print(item.pk, item.info_court, item.info_court_id, item.worker)
court_info_id = accident.court_info.pk
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CourtForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print('CourtForm', form)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)

        form.info_court.pk = court_info_id
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
CourtForms = CourtForm()
template_name = 'dist/court/event/read_court_add_event.html'
data = {'court_info': court_info,
        'court': CourtForms,
        'court_list': court_list,
        'accident_pk': accident_pk
        }
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите